# Easier alternative for showing Button as pressed or not than Selector?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-button

I have an application with a large number of buttons across the various screens. Each of the buttons has a background image as well as text (so ImageButton is no good). I am aware that it's possible to have multiple versions of an image for the different states a button can be in (e.g. pressed and not pressed), that it's possible to put the different versions of the image in a selector, and then to set the background of the button to be the selector. However, this means I need to create two versions of each image (times four for each of the different densities I'm considering) and thus bloating the size of my apk as well as adding considerable time to produce the duplicate images.

Is this the only way to change the look of a button for when it's pressed or not (i.e. to set its background to be a selector which links to two different images), or is there some other easier way to change the look of a button, like specifying some built-in property of the button (its 'darkness' for example)?

Comment: Depending on your background you could try to make a shape and use it. You can also change the text color as a response...

Comment: Shapes no good for my purpose as the images have designs/pictures/etc on them. Like the idea of changing text color. Didn't think of that/ Not ideal but definitely useful if I'm running out of time and space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one way of showing a `View` as pressed or not by wrapping the `View` in a `FrameLayout`, giving the `FrameLayout` a `foreground` drawable which is a `selector` consisting of a black-ish transparent colour (pressed state) and fully transparent colour (default state), and then setting the click listener on the `FrameLayout` instead of the `View`. Wrote it out in greater detail on my Blog here:

http://adilatwork.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/android-show-view-as-pressed-without.html